# Challanges to integrate sum types into json/protobuffer/toml/yaml?

Tags: union-types

What challenges might arise when integrating sum types into data exchange or configuration file formats such as json, protobuf, toml or yaml?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks multiple questions; all those data exchange formats are quite different and would have different approaches.

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms that's possible :p

Comment: @Seggan That sounds like 'needs more focus' to me.

Comment: @user16217248 ah yes of course theres a close reason i overlooked

Comment: What does "integrating sum types into ... json, protobuf, toml or yaml" even mean? Representing elements of sum types in those languages is already trivially easy.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how easy it is to differentiate the types, you might be forced to make sum types tagged. For example, a type `float | int` would be impossible to infer from JSON, as `JSON.stringify({a: 1.0}) === '{"a":1}'` on most JS implementations.

Comment: This looks like a union type to me, not a sum type. A sum type is a tagged union.

Comment: @kaya3 oops, I thought they were synonyms, tmyk

Answer (score 0):

Swift has native sum types with `enum`, and serialization in the standard library with `Codable`. `Codable` is usually used for JSON, but it's meant to be format-agnostic. So, let's see how it handles this:

```swift
enum SumType: Codable {
  case i(Int)
  case d(Double)
}
```

It encodes this as a nested object ([example](https://swiftfiddle.com/a4v4bcuy7bazzcl6w2x7x4vdxi)):

```json
{ "i": { "_0": 5 } }
// or
{ "d": { "_0": 0.5 } }
```

The key `_0` is just the default as it's an unlabelled value; you're allowed to have things like this:

```swift
enum MyError {
  case unrecoverable(message: String)
  case recoverable(message: String, suggestions: [String])
}
```

In which case the keys of the inner object would be `message` and `suggestions` rather than `_0` or similar.

This approach is amenable to JSON, YAML, and TOML, which all support nested objects. I'm not familiar with protobuf, but given how common nested structures are in code, I'd be very surprised if that doesn't support them.